# Add type descriptors to all List<T> for a generic implementation of property grid expansion?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, propertygrid, typedescriptor

I defined a custom `ExpandableObjectConverter` for collections:

```
internal class ExpandableCollectionConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        //implementation that returns a list of property descriptors,
        //one for each item in "value"
    }
}
```

And also have a proxy class called `ExpandableObjectManager`, which in essence does this:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(type,
  new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableCollectionConverter)));
```

Using this method:

```
public static class ExpandableObjectManager
{
    public static void AddTypeDescriptor(Type tItem)
    {
        //eventually calls TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add type descriptor in such a way that all generic `List<T>` will be expandable in the property grid? For example, given a simple `Employee` class:

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

I can do this (and it works, but only for `List<Employee>`):

```
ExpandableObjectManager.AddTypeDescriptor(typeof(List<Employee>));
```

I would like to cover all `T`, not just `Employee`, without having to write 1 line for each possible class. I tried this - didn't work:

```
ExpandableObjectManager.AddTypeDescriptor(typeof(List<>));
```

---

**TL;DR:** Default view of a List when set as `SelectedObject` in the property grid:

[image]

Expected results:

[image]

Without having to add a type descriptor for `List<Employee>`, and instead having some generic handler for all `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I added a third possibility.

I don't think any of these are wonderful solutions but here are three possibilities:

Add TypeConverterAttribute to an interface that the generic type implements.  The downside here is that you may not precisely hit the types you are targetting, but it is better than option 2 because it is quite a bit more focused on the types you want.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(IList), new
    TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableCollectionConverter)));
```

Add the TypeConverterAttribute to the `object` type.  The downside is that this will make your type converter the type converter for all types in your project.

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(object), new
    TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableCollectionConverter)));
```

Create your own list type that inherits from `List<>` and have it register itself in the static constructor

```
public class CustomList<T> : List<T>
{
    static CustomList()
    {
        TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(CustomList<T>), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableCollectionConverter)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, neither option works for me, because #1 some objects already have a good implementation of an expandable object converter, which I would break, if I set my own. For example, enums. #2 I don't want to create a custom class to represent List<T>. It adds unnecessary complexity to the program. Also existing assemblies can't use it.

Comment: Totally understandable.  If I find a better option, I will share it.

Comment: I added a third option.  I listed it first because it seems the most viable yet.